# Kafka connect to Bigquery connector without schema registry giving error

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect

I have an issue in saving to bigquery without providing schema.

Kafka connect Config

```
tasks.max: 1
topics: sample_topic
project: gcp-project-name
defaultDataset: dataset-name
keyfile: key_file_path
group.id: bq-connector
confluent.license: licence_file_path
```

Error

```
[2021-12-01 11:10:16,554] ERROR Task failed with com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.exception.BigQueryConnectException error: Failed to unionize schemas of records for the table GenericData{classInfo=[datasetId, projectId, tableId], {datasetId=dataset_name, tableId=table_name}} (com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.KCBQThreadPoolExecutor:70)
Exception in thread "pool-9-thread-1" com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.exception.BigQueryConnectException: Failed to unionize schemas of records for the table GenericData{classInfo=[datasetId, projectId, tableId], {datasetId=dataset_name, tableId=table_name}}
Caused by: Could not convert to BigQuery schema with a batch of tombstone records.
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.SchemaManager.getTableInfo(SchemaManager.java:283)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.SchemaManager.createTable(SchemaManager.java:226)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.attemptTableCreate(AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.java:168)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.performWriteRequest(AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.java:115)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.BigQueryWriter.writeRows(BigQueryWriter.java:118)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.TableWriter.run(TableWriter.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.exception.BigQueryConnectException: Could not convert to BigQuery schema with a batch of tombstone records.
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.SchemaManager.getAndValidateProposedSchema(SchemaManager.java:301)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.SchemaManager.getTableInfo(SchemaManager.java:280)
    ... 8 more
[2021-12-01 11:10:16,606] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=kafka-to-bigquery-sink-connector-0} Offset commit failed, rewinding to last committed offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:385)
```

**Edit 1:**

I added below configs, but same error

```
allowBigQueryRequiredFieldRelaxation: true
allBQFieldsNullable: true
```

Comment: `See logs for more detail`... Can you provide more logs? Otherwise, as the error says, null values (tombstone records) cannot be written in the connector

Comment: Added detailed logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting strong boundaries to config works at best.

After reading [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-bigquery/current/kafka_connect_bigquery_config.html) and other discussions, found a few more properties to set correctly as below.

```
sanitizeTopics: false
autoCreateTables: false
autoUpdateSchemas: false
schemaRetriever: com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.retrieve.IdentitySchemaRetriever
bufferSize: 100
maxWriteSize: 100
tableWriteWait: 1000
timestamp: UTC
bigQueryPartitionDecorator: false
```